# Solving the equation $(1+y^2) \,\mathrm{d}x = (\tan^{-1}y - x)\,\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please help with this calculus question. I'm asked to solve
$$(1+y^2) \,\mathrm{d}x = (\tan^{-1}y - x)\,\mathrm{d}y.$$

Comment: Suppose you make a change of variable such as y = Tan[z]. Would this simplify the problem ?

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

The ODE 
$$
(1+y^2)+(x-\arctan y)y'=0\tag 1
$$
is not exact because, putting $M(x,y)=1+y^2$ and $N(x,y)=x-\arctan y$,  $$M_y=\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2y\neq 1=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=N_x.$$
We have to find an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ such that 
$$\frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x}$$
that is 
$$
\mu'(1+y^2)+2y\mu=\mu
$$
and isolating $\mu$ 
$$
\frac{\mu'}{\mu}=\frac{1-2y}{1+y^2}.
$$
Integrating we have
$$
\log\mu=\arctan y-\log(1+y^2)
$$
that is 
$$
\mu(y)=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}}{1+y^2}
$$
Multiplying the eq. (1) by $\mu$ 
$$
\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}+\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}}{1+y^2}(x-\arctan y)y'=0\tag 2
$$
and calling $$P(x,y)=\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}$$ and $$Q(x,y)=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}}{1+y^2}(x-\arctan y)$$ we see that the eq. (2) is exact because $$P_y=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}}{1+y^2}=Q_x.$$

Then, defining $f(x,y)$ such that $f_x=P$ and $f_y=Q$, the solution will be given by $f(x,y)=K$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant.

Integrating $f_x$ with respect to $x$ we have
$$
f(x,y)=\int f_x\operatorname{d}x=\int \operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}\operatorname{d}x=\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}x+g(y)
$$
with $g(y)$ an arbitrary function of $y$.

Differentiating with respect to $y$ and observing that $f_y=Q$ we find
$$
g'(y)=-\frac{\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}}{1+y^2}\arctan y
$$
and integrating we'll have
$$
g(y)=\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}(1-\arctan y).
$$
Substituting $g(y)$ into $f(x,y)$ we have
$$
f(x,y)=\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}(1+x-\arctan y)
$$
and the solution will be given by $f(x,y)=K$, that is
$$
\operatorname{e}^{\arctan y}(1+x-\arctan y)=K.\tag 3
$$

**NOTE**

If you kow the Lambert $W$-function, also called the omega function,  defined as the function $W(z)$ that satisfies
$$W(z)\operatorname{e}^{W(z)}=z$$
you can express $y(x)$ from eq. (3) as
$$
y(x)=\tan\left(1+x+W\left(-K\operatorname{e}^{-(1+x)}\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**
 we can write the given equation as,

```
    dx/dy = {tan^(-1)y -x} / {1 + y^(2)}
    dx/dy + x/{1 + y^(2)} = tan^(-1)y /{1 + y^(2)}
```

the above one is a linear differential equation in x.
therefore, Integrating factor = exp^[ ∫ 1/{1 + y^(2)} dy]
                              = exp^{tan^(-1)y}

Hence we get the solution as,

```
                x.(integrating factor) = ∫ [ (Integrating factor).{tan^(-1)y /(1 + y^(2))}] dy  + C (some constant)

                x.exp^{tan^(-1)y} = exp^{tan^(-1)y} . [tan^(-1)y - 1] + C

                { 1 + x + tan^(-1)y }.exp^{tan^(-1)y} = C


                which is the required solution.
```